# Cannot destructure property 'Sha256' of 'sha256_js_1.default' as it is undefined

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jestjs, aws-sdk

I am currently doing some work on a AWS-Lambda and as part of that project I am using `"@aws-crypto/sha256-js"` in my project.
When I bring in Sha256 as per the Amplify documentation https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/graphql-from-nodejs/q/platform/js/#iam-authorization and deploy the lambda everything works as expected. However, when running my tests with Jest I am receiving the following error:

```
    TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'Sha256' of 'sha256_js_1.default' as it is undefined.

      4 | import { default as fetch, Request } from "node-fetch";
      5 | import crypto from "@aws-crypto/sha256-js";
    > 6 | const { Sha256 } = crypto;
```

I have read quite a bit of documentation and questions/answers on this and I am marking it up as this particular package having some kind of issue or Jest has some kind of issue with this package, but I could be wrong.

The deployed lambda works as expected and TypeScript is giving me auto-complete for when I bring in `{Sha256}` from crypto. Any help in getting rid of this annoying error would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error usually comes from not having `"esModuleInterop": true` set in your tsconfig.json file (more information can be found at this link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop)

You can either set `"esModuleInterop": true`, or you can use the import star syntax:

```js
import * as crypto from "@aws-crypto/sha256-js";
const { Sha256 } = crypto;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this worked! Not sure why though...

Comment: Oh wait, my bad I didn't notice you're using TypeScript until now; this error usually has to do with the `esModuleInterop` option in tsconfig.json, make sure that value is set to `true` for compatibility with CommonJS modules (and I think `@aws-crypto/sha256-js` is a CommonJS module) and then you can use the regular import syntax; Link for more info: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop

Comment: Amazing, thanks for this. It is a commonJS module!